How to show (auto load on click of New Email button) the task pane (outlook web add-in) in the Outlook when the user is composing an email?
I'm developing an Outlook Web add-in for Outlook. I would like to see the Web Add-in task pane when composing a new email in outlook.
Using event-based activation, I can fire an event when a new email button is pressed in outlook, but unable to auto load web add-in the task pane.
The site below calls the Office.addin.showAsTaskpane() method to show the task pane, but it is not working for Outlook web add-in.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in
Are there other ways to show the Outlook web add-ins task pane in Outlook on click of New Email button?
Tried: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/show-hide-add-in
Current behavior
Errror while loading the web add-in in Outlook on click of New Email button (Email compose screen)
ADD-IN ERROR

 We can't start this add-in because it isn't set up properly

Expected behavior
Web Add-in task pane should load when composing a new email in outlook (on click of New Email button in Outlook)
Steps to reproduce

Build addin from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-Add-in-samples/tree/main/Samples/hello-world/outlook-hello-world

Sideload manifest in Outlook for Windows

Click on "New Email"

This should trigger the OnNewMessageCompose and thus open a Taskpane.


most relevant code snippets:
manifest.xml:
<ExtensionPoint>       <LaunchEvents>               <LaunchEvent Type="OnNewMessageCompose" FunctionName="onNewMessageComposeHandler"/>             </LaunchEvents> </ExtensionPoint>     <Runtimes> <Runtime resid="WebViewRuntime.Url" lifetime="long"> </Runtime>     <Requirements>       <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.10">         <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.10" />       </bt:Sets>     </Requirements>     

javascript code:
Office.actions.associate("onNewMessageComposeHandler", onNewMessageComposeHandler); function onNewMessageComposeHandler(event) {     Office.addin.showAsTaskpane();     event.completed();   }

